# Software for web server client side file management

Tags: web-apps, file-management, dashboard

I would like to find software that allows my client (I do web design) to write to and delete from a specific folder in the web server.

The website dynamically loads and displays images from this folder so **I want to give my client some sort of dashboard that they can use to upload, remove, rename etc. images inside this folder**. Currently, the website doesn't use any kind of CMS. I would like something:

- Simplistic, not a full-blown CMS like Wordpress.
- Preferably something that's also accessible through a mobile app so that my client can manage their website content from a phone or tablet.
- Featuring user management so that only authorized users can modify this folder's contents.

OwnCloud comes to mind, but I haven't been able to set it up for an existing folder.

In case it's relevant: the client is running Windows.

Comment: If that web app is already in place, why not serving that one folder via FTP/SCP so the client can use e.g. WinSCP to manage those files? Just make sure that OS user owns the directory (and has read-write permission), while the group of the directory is that of the web server (with read-only permissions).

Comment: I would love to be able to offer them FTP access and chroot them to that folder, but I doubt they'd be happy with an interface like FileZilla, for example. Consider my client is extremely uneducated when it comes to technology. They once sent me 14 emails with one image in each in less than 10 minutes. An FTP client that plays similar to Dropbox would be awesome.

Comment: No idea how dropbox plays. But if opening a folder and drag&dropping files is fine, there are SSHFS apps available for Windows (I know because I've once used one for a customer). See [ExpanDrive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpanDrive). Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, in fact there are several free candidates (see Wikipedia's [Comparison of FTP client software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_FTP_client_software)). If that's what it should be, I withdraw from recommending ExpanDrive for budget reasons (it starts at ~USD 50 for a single-user license). Good luck and enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could give your client (presumably using Windows) instructions on how to map a network drive using FTP. This is software that comes with I believe Windows 7 and up. It's very easy to setup and only takes about a minute or two. I would recommend using [this guide](http://cybernetnews.com/cybernotes-map-a-ftp-to-a-drive-in-windows/), it provides a step by step guide with pictures. Once setup, it then acts as a drive on your computer which he can then see anything that his FTP account has access to where he could upload images how he likes along with the ability to rename and delete images as well. It meets your requirements of,

- Being simplistic (FTP should not be too hard to setup)
- There are FTP apps for most mobile devices
- FTP basically has accounts which you can manage which users have access to certain folders and you can also setup file quotas.